# Does running a tor bridge from the same public IP as a relay before make such bridge prone to censorship?

Tags: relays, bridge, censorship, middle

My ISP changes my public IP about once a year. I used to run a public middle relay for a couple of weeks, and then I changed my mind and decided to operate a bridge.
Let us assume that my adversary censored the access to the service that my relay provided (public IPs of the relays are publicly viewable in the directory
of the Tor relays). Having removed the relay, does running a bridge afterwards, from the same computer connected to the same router, expose such a bridge to an additional risk of censorship? Does it even make any sense to try?

Answer (score 1):

It's ok: if any adversary *is* active looking for *public* bridges like in BridgeDB - it will not save you. No significant differences at all